# kendo ui api overwrite

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, overriding

I'm using the kendoUi pack. I have the kendo Ui window which I want to be able to open at the center of the screen not the html document. Therefore I want to overwrite the open event of the window to be able to overwrite the position where the window opens for every control in the application.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the options of the window manually with JS. 
This is a modded version of my own kWindow setup function.

```
function WindowSetup(winId, x, y) {
  var wind = $("#" + winId).data("kendoWindow");

  wind.setOptions({
    position: {top:x, left:y}
  });

  wind.open();

  return wind;
}
```

This should allow you to set the position manually.

---

You can also set the height width and default content.

This is the original version of my kWindow setup (Note: I just center the content here)
This will auto re-size the window to fill most of the browsers window or the full window if it on a small screen.

```
//Sets up the base window settings
//bLoad is if you are waiting for a ajax call to return the window content
//returns the kendoWindow widget instance
function WindowSetup(winId, bLoad) {
  var wind = $("#" + winId).data("kendoWindow");
  wind.restore();

  wind.setOptions({
    width: $(window).innerWidth() - ($(window).innerWidth() / 5),
    height: $(window).innerHeight() - ($(window).innerHeight() / 5)
  });

  //if True or Undifined we reset the content. False skips.
  if (bLoad !== false) {
    wind.content("<div class='k-loading-image'>&nbsp;</div>");
  }

  wind.center();
  wind.open();

  // If small screen size, open window full-screen
  if ($(window).innerWidth() < 600 || $(window).innerHeight() < 600) {
    wind.maximize();
  }

  return wind;
}
```